# Can I position the current line in the Windows Terminal a few lines off the bottom of the screen?

Tags: windows-terminal

On Windows 10 using the Windows Terminal (v1.6). Is there a setting to add a few lines of "margin" to the terminal window so it's not continually glued to the bottom of the viewport? I use terminal in full screen and it's not convenient to change to floating window mode in order to provide this margin.

I know this sounds kinda weird--why remove space from the display? I'm using RDP to log into my remote system. My home machine is a laptop. There is a resolution mismatch between laptop (3k) and my second monitor. This causes an annoying misalignment when my mouse "touches" the edge of the screen, and my home machine's desktop Toolbar makes an appearance in my remote session (crazy, but not asking for help with that problem) and covers up the last line in Windows Terminal. I can reset the window by hiding RDP session and unhiding it, but when working quickly it would be nice to just have a few lines to ignore the issue a little longer. (>_<)

Comment: why not edit your [settings.json to define the terminals initial rows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/startup#rows-on-first-launch) to a value suited to your situation?

Comment: Will that work?  The question mentions that the OP is using WT in "full screen", which sounds to me like `maximizedFocus` mode, which that doc says will ignore `initialRows`, right?  A lot of solutions that I can think of will be invalidated if the OP is set on using full-screen, I believe.

Comment: Just had a chance to try it.  It seems that "fullscreen" is different than "maximizedFocus", but "fullscreen" mode still doesn't respect `initialRows`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for the `"padding"` setting, which can be applied at the `"profiles"` level, either for a particular profile, or in the `"defaults"` for all profiles ([doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-appearance#window)).

E.g.

```
    "profiles":
    {
        "defaults":
        {
            // Put settings here that you want to apply to all profiles.
            //"useAcrylic": true, 
            //"acrylicOpacity": 0.75

            // Default is 8,8,8,8
            // 100 is probably overkill but good to demonstrate
            "padding": "8,8,8,100",

            // From Nerd Fonts
            // https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts
            "fontFace": "CaskaydiaCove NF",

            "fontSize": 13,
            "cursorShape": "filledBox"
        },
        "list":
...
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed--perfect. Thank you.